# Python: skip every nth element in hashcheck, conditional mismatch?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I currently have a script that generates hashes from the contents of a text file and saves them to a dictionary, and it then goes into a second text file and generates hashes from there and compares them to said dictionary. I'm trying to implement some sort of incomplete matching; for example, I want to program some tolerance: for example, I'd like to make it so that every third element in the hash is unimportant to the matching protocol, so if there is a mismatch, it will continue iterating unimpeded. Is it possible to do this?

Furthermore, and this is a separate case, would it be possible to determine a conditional mismatch? For example, if there is a mismatch, there are several elements that would still qualify as "matching", like if I wanted a vowel at a certain position, but it didn't matter which vowel showed up.

In summary, I'm trying to make it so that my script either goes

check,check,disregard,check,check,disregard,etc.

OR

check,check,conditional mismatch?,check,check,conditional mismatch?,etc.

along the hashes. Is this doable?

EDIT: I suppose it's not really hashchecking, but more of string comparison. Here's the relevant code I'm trying to tweak:

```
# hash table for finding hits
lookup = defaultdict(list)

# store sequence hashes in hash table
for i in xrange(len(file1) - hashlen + 1):
    key = file1[i:i+hashlen]
    lookup[key].append(i)

# look up hashes in hash table
hits = []
for i in xrange(len(file2) - hashlen + 1):
    key = file2[i:i+hashlen]

    # store hits to hits list
    for hit in lookup.get(key, []):
        hits.append((i, hit))
```

where hashlen is the length of the hash I want to generate (and thus the buffer so I don't go off the end of the file.

Comment: Hashes(dicts) don't support indexing, so there's no concept of third or fourth item.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I'm not sure its clear that he meant dictionaries when he says "hashes". He also refers to dictionaries using the proper name, so I think his hashes might be something else. Happydude800, can you elaborate more on what you mean by "hashes" Can you show some of your code?

Comment: Could you post some code showing what you've tried so far please?

Comment: I've edited my question with the relevant code block. Hope that helps. I was originally trying to see if there was a general example that could be generated, but pre-conceived code always helps, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, hashes do not have order. You can consider using an OrderedDict.

But maybe this code help you.

```
skip_rate = 3

for index, (key, value) in enumerate(your_hash.items()):
    if index % skip_rate != 0:
        do_something(key, value)
```